# Angular directive second parameter, why is it a function?

Tags: angularjs, directive

This is just a general question about Angular directives. Why does angular choose to have a function that returns an object and not just list the object directly as the second parameter?

in other words, why does it look like this:

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>'
  };
});
```

and not this:

```
app.directive('helloWorld',{
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>'
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so you can inject dependencies

for example:

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>'
  };
});
```

angular will inject the $rootScope into your directive.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you instantiate a directive you want a new instance of it. The function will instantiate a new object for you as opposed to returning the same object.

Additionally the function can also be used for Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is to allow for dependency injection ex.

```
.directive('someDirective', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            });
        }
    };
}]);
```